# Cleaning articles

Tags: word-meaning

Is a trolley a cleaning article?

The room was stuffed/containing with a trolley and (other) cleaning articles.

Also, can I use both stuffed and containing in the sentence?

Comment: Please do some research. A trolley may have cleaning products in it or on it. But a trolley is not a cleaning article.

Comment: One trolley and some cleaning articles would hardly "stuff" a room. But, "The room was containing with a trolley" does not work grammatically. "The room contained a trolley."

Comment: What can I describe a trolley as then: a cleaning... what?

Comment: A trolley is just a trolley. Maybe a 'cleaner's trolley'.

Comment: You could reverse the sentence and say: *The room (was filled with / contained) cleaning supplies and **related equipment**, (including a trolley).* A trolley doesn't serve the specific purpose of cleaning—unless perhaps a sticker reading *Only for cleaning!* has been attached to it, but that would be a forced meaning and not very normal. It would also be used to aid in cleaning (putting things on), not to actually perform any cleaning activity itself. But mainly, a trolley is not an article; it's a piece of equipment. (And *cleaning supplies* is far more idiomatic than *cleaning articles*.)